# I want to convert decimal number to 8 bits of binary number and perform even parity using c language

Tags: c, binary

This is the code I have written for getting an 8-bit binary number but I am facing a problem in doing even parity using C language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_LP64)
# define BUILD_64   1
#endif

#ifdef BUILD_64
# define BITS_PER_LONG 64
#else
# define BITS_PER_LONG 32
#endif

char *binstr (unsigned long n, size_t sz);


int main (void) {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the decimal number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf ("%s \n\n", binstr (n, 8));

    return 0;
}

/* returns pointer to binary representation of 'n' zero padded to 'sz'. */
char *binstr (unsigned long n, size_t sz)
{
    static char s[BITS_PER_LONG + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + BITS_PER_LONG;
    register size_t i;

    if (!n) {
        *s = '0';
        return s;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        *(--p) = (n>>i & 1) ? '1' : '0';

    return p;
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be doing any parity check.

Comment: Aside: instead of engaging conditional compilation directives, consider `#define BITS_PER_LONG (sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT)`.  That does assume that there are no padding bits in your implementation's `long`, but you seem already to be assuming that anyway.

Comment: Anyway, by "perform even parity", do you mean "check whether the input has even parity"?  What is the issue there?

Comment: Another option: Instead of checking how many bits there are in an `unsigned long`, you could probably use a type with the number of bits you want, like `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`.

Comment: I have to change the binary number to even parity. That is if there are even number of 1s then i have to add 1 to 9th bit or else add 0 to 9th bit

Answer (score 0):

To calculate parity you do not need to convert to binary form:

```
int parity(uint64_t v)
{
    v = v ^ (v >> 32);
    v = v ^ (v >> 16);
    v = v ^ (v >> 8);
    v = v ^ (v >> 4);
    return (0b0110100110010110 >> (v & 0xf)) & 1;
}
```

PS I could screw up the lookup table (16 bits binary number) - but I think it is ok. It is even parity bit for numbers from `15` to `0` looking from left to right (parity of 15 is MSB).

EDIT. As converting to even parity is not very understandable you can for example add 1 to the number not having even parity. You can shift it left and add one etc, etc.

```
uint64_t convert1(uint64_t v)
{
    if(!parity(v)) v++;
    return v;
}
uint64_t convert2(uint64_t v)
{
    if(!parity(v)) v = (v << 1) + 1;
    return v;
}
```

> I have to change the binary number to even parity. That is if there
> are even number of 1s then i have to add 1 to 9th bit or else add 0 to
> 9th bit

```
int parity(uint8_t v)
{
    v = v ^ (v >> 4);
    return (0b0110100110010110 >> (v & 0xf)) & 1;
}

uint16_t convert1(uint8_t v)   // 9th bit is LSB
{
    uint16_t v1 = v ;
    v1 = (v1 << 1) + !parity(v);
    return v1;
}

uint16_t convert2(uint8_t v) // 9th bit is MSB
{
    uint16_t v1 = v;
    if(!parity(v)) v1 = v1 | (1 << 8);
    return v1;
}

//or 

uint16_t convert2(uint8_t v) // 9th bit is MSB
{
    uint16_t v1 = v;
    v1 = v1 | ((!parity(v)) << 8);
    return v1;
}
```

Complete program:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int parity(uint8_t v)
{
    v = v ^ (v >> 4);
    return (0b0110100110010110 >> (v & 0xf)) & 1;
}

uint16_t convert1(uint8_t v)   // 9th bit is LSB
{
    uint16_t v1 = v ;
    v1 = (v1 << 1) + parity(v);
    return v1;
}

uint16_t convert2(uint8_t v) // 9th bit is MSB
{
    uint16_t v1 = v;
    if(parity(v)) v1 = v1 | (1 << 8);
    return v1;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned num ;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter number (0-255)"); 
        if(scanf("%u", &num) != 1 || num > 255)
        {
            printf("Wrong input!! Try Again\n");
            num = UINT_MAX;
        }
    }
    while(num == UINT_MAX);

    printf("Number entered: %u, even parity number  = LSB(%u) MSB(%u)\n", num, convert1(num), convert2(num));
}
```

Comment: i dont have to calculate parity. I have to change the binary number to even parity.

Comment: @AkshatPattiwar what does it mean convert?

Comment: It means that we have to make the binary number even parity. That is add 1 at the 9th bit if the number of 1s in binary number is even else add 0 at 9th bit

Comment: @AkshatPattiwar very easy - see answer

Comment: @AkshatPattiwar you need to do some work yourself.

Comment: I tried its not working. I have done half of the question by myself. Just facing problem in this even parity. Padding is done

Answer (score 0):

To find odd parity of a `uint8_t`:

```
// return 1 when the number of 1 bits is odd
bool odd_parity(uint8_t n) {
  n ^= n >> 4;
  n ^= n >> 2;
  n ^= n >> 1;
  return n & 1;
}
```

> to change the binary number to even parity. That is if there are even number of 1s then i have to add 1 to 9th bit or else add 0 to 9th bit

"... if there are even number of 1s ..." --> that is *even* parity.  Adding 1 to 9th bit makes parity *odd*.

Goal sounds more like insuring the result has *odd* parity.

```
unsigned AP_Parity(uint8_t n) {
  return (odd_parity(n) << 8) | n;
}
```

Comment: ya result should have odd parity